# Jhipster hide bearer token

Tags: jhipster

I'm using jhipster with jwt token to authen. But after login, jhipster stored token in localstore of browser. If i copy it and paste to another browser and F5, it auto login there. So if hacker have token, they can login without password rite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, this is why tokens should have a short life duration and should be refreshed often (but JHipster JWT has no refresh, JHipster OAuth2 has it).

As an alternative you could pass the token in a cookie (secure and httpOnly) so that it can't be read by JS code but again if your cookie is stolen, you'll be in same state unless you combine with CSRF.

For JHipster applications:

- For a monolith, session-based auth is more secure than JWT.
- For microservices, OAuth2 is a better choice than JWT.

You could also add the IP address as a claim to your token and verify it matches the request in server.

Comment: can i ask you how to save token in cookie with secure and httpOnly and how to read it value. tks you

Comment: This is done server side in java backend and you can't read its value in frontend because that's the whole point of setting it as httpOnly. Browser sends it back to server automatically with each request, nothing to code. Monolith or microservice? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38341114/spring-security-cookie-jwt-authentication